# jquery StrutsTypeConverter json struts2 does not convert

Tags: calendar, jsonresult

I have a problem with struts2-json-plugin and StrutsTypeConverter.
I have a result of a DB which contains java.util.Calendar entries.

And I have a public class CalendarTypeConverter extends StrutsTypeConverter, which converts the DB resutl to a date String.

When I use Struts2 tags , the converter is called and the conversion is done. When I use org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult for a jQuery grid, the converter is not used, no conversion is done.

How can I get a JSON-Result with converted Calendar data?

Answer (score 0):

You need a javaScript to make this work.

In colModel
use something like this

```
{name:'dateOfBirth', formatter:'date', formatter:formatCalendarDay()}
```

create a grid function like:  This function returns in format mm/dd/yyyy.  You can check your string format needed.

```
formatCalendarDay: function() {
        return function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
            if (cellvalue != null) {
                return cellvalue.month + '/' + cellvalue.day + '/' + cellvalue.year;
            } else {
                return ' ';
            }
        };
    },
```